# How do I create an Azure SQL Database copy during runtime?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, copy, azure-sql-database

I am new to VB.NET and Azure SQL services and I have spent the last 3 days searching for an answer and cannot come up with an answer I can truly understand.   Here is my scenario and problem:

I have a VB.NET application where a user will log into their account and have their own set of tables under their own Azure SQL Database.  I would like my program to automatically create their database for them (using their own selected name), which would be a database copy of an existing empty Database in Azure.

I can already access the data tables in my master database, but I do not know how to make a copy of it from my program during runtime.  When I run my application and it debugs the following snippit of code, I get an exception error saying "You must be logged into the master database"  I'm not sure how to resolve that error from popping up as I am using the master admin account in my normal SQL connection string.

```
Private Sub BtnActivate_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If passwrd1.Password <> passwrd2.Password Then
        MsgBox("Password doesn't match Confirm Password.", vbOKOnly)
    Else
        Dim commandString = "CREATE DATABASE " & dbname.Text & " AS COPY OF DBDEV;"
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBDEVConnectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandString, connection)
            Try
                connection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("DATABASE SETUP.  USE " & dbname.Text & "AS DBNAME TO CONNECT TO")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help, I've been moving nowhere and everything I'm searching for doesn't give me a clear answer to this simple scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I solved the problem:  in my connection string, I had the initial catalog default to my database and so I changed it to say "master" (even though I don't have a database named master) and it performed the Database copy for me.  Woohoo!